# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 0 of undefined

Tags: javascript, bar-chart

I'm trying to make a bar chart sorter. On button click it will sort the bar graph. But when I run the sort function, it gives me this error.
I've tried searching my file for typos, as that is what was recommended on other answers.

Thanks in advance.

Here's my JS:

```js
document.getElementById('sort').onclick = () => {
        setTimeout(function(){
              for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
              let g = document.getElementsByClassName('bar');
              g[i].style.height = sort()[i]
              console.log(sort()[i])
        }},100)
}

function sort() {
    let array = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        let g = document.getElementsByClassName('bar');
        array.push(parseInt(g[i].innerText));
        if (i >= 8) {
            return sortItems(array)
        }
    }
}

function sortItems(array) { 
    var length = array.length; 
  
      for(var i = 1, j; i < length; i++) { 
        var temp1 = array[i]; 
        for(var j = i - 1; j >= 0 && array[j] > temp1; j--) { 
          array[j+1] = array[j]; 
        } 
        array[j+1] = temp1; 
      } 
    return array; 
  }
```

And here's my html:

```html
<button id="regenerate">Regenerate</button>
    <button id="sort">Sort</button>
    <div class="bars">
        <div class="bar" id="bar1"><p class="barlabel"></p></div>
        <div class="bar" id="bar2"><p class="barlabel"></p></div>
        <div class="bar" id="bar3"><p class="barlabel"></p></div>
        <div class="bar" id="bar4"><p class="barlabel"></p></div>
        <div class="bar" id="bar5"><p class="barlabel"></p></div>
        <div class="bar" id="bar6"><p class="barlabel"></p></div>
        <div class="bar" id="bar7"><p class="barlabel"></p></div>
        <div class="bar" id="bar8"><p class="barlabel"></p></div>
    </div>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
```

Comment: The error includes which line it was caused by. Look closer at that line, it will help you find the problem. In general you should get in the habit of reading errors to help debug, not skimming over them.

Comment: I have checked. I don't see anything wrong. `g[i].style.height = sort()[i]`

Comment: Check the error again and compare it to your code. i is zero, and it's trying to read the zeroth element of an array that isn't defined. It's not a typo, it's an error that happens when the code is executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look at this for loop in the sort() function:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        let g = document.getElementsByClassName('bar');
        array.push(parseInt(g[i].innerText));
        if (i >= 8) {
            return sortItems(array)
        }
}
```

It only returns an array if `i >= 8` but the loop itself will only iterate as long as `i < 8`. That means the sort() function will never return anything.

In this line `g[i].style.height = sort()[i]` you expect an array as return value of `sort()`, but it actually is `undefined`. Just proof it with `console.log(typeof sort())`.